# When you are designing a device with a CPU that only supports ddr3, is it possible to use ddr2 in that design instead?

Tags: microprocessor

[Sitara™ AM57x Processors](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/processors/sitara/arm_cortex-a15/am57x/overview.page)

I want to make a system and have access to ddr2 ram slot design files only. How can I re-route the controller to use ddr2 sodimm memory with a ddr3 interface. I am designing my own board.

Comment: Does the Sitara AM57X processor have enough pins to drive a SODIMM socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (*).

DDR3 is not backwards compatible with DDR2 and vice versa. You can't attach DDR2 RAM and expect a DDR3 external memory interface controller to work with it.

Your best bet is simply to design around DDR3 and update your design files.

---

(*) You *could* get an FPGA and write some controller to allow it to appear as DDR3 memory, and have it interface with the DDR2 memory as effectively some form of translation, but that is really a pointless idea as it would take far more time, effort, and cost to do compared with just designing a DDR3 PCB footprint.

Comment: surely the FPGA would never be anywhere near fast enough as a proper DDR memory connection? Think of the latency!

Comment: @KyranF you never know, you can get FPGAs that will do DDR4. But yes it is a bad idea, it was a suggestion meant only to reinforce why upgrading any designs the OP has to DDR3 is the better course of action.

Comment: @KyranF,  All modern FPGAs come with IP that allow an on-board DDR2, DDR3, and DDR4 controllers supporting speeds up to 667MHz, both for individual chips, and for SO-DIMM sockets, see for example Kintex-7 development platforms, http://www.hitechglobal.com/boards/allboards.htm

Comment: The reason I want to to this is so that I can use a raspberry pi compute module. It uses a ddr2 interface.

Comment: @JonathanS. then find a different CPU that a DDR2 interface. The two memories are not compatible.

Comment: @AliChen I didn't say whether or not FPGAs could interface with DDR RAM, the issue is making a pseudo DDR interface using an FPGA with another device. A pass-through controller basically - surely there are massive drawbacks with that.

Comment: @KyranF, if a FPGA can interface with 667MHz DDR3, it can interface with 333MHz DDR2. The interface is already clock-serial, and CAS-RAS delays should give plenty of time. However,the challenge will be to emulate DDR3 side (facing the MCU), which is likely a well-kept secret, and would require a lot of work. Reducing throughput to DDR2 rate might be a problem too.